# MediaElement web Video doesn't stop buffering

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, mediaelement

I m using MediaElement to play a web video. When I left the page I noticed in the Task Manager that my app was still using 10% of network and didn't drop till it finished downloading video.

I tried doing the following but no luck.

```
    //open link;
    mediaElement.Source = welcomeVideoURL;

    //when I leave the page OnNavigatedFrom()
    mediaElement.Stop();
    mediaElement.ClearValue(MediaElement.SourceProperty);
    mediaElement.Source = null;
```

Also tried to set the source to a dummy link but still no luck.

I thought that opening the Link as a Stream and use `mediaElement.SetSource()` could work but I haven't found anything on that...maybe I m not searching correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried without `mediaElement.AudioCategory = AudioCategory.ForegroundOnlyMedia`. And, is your server capable to handle HTTP Range? If it doesn't, there is no way to download the video in parts and it should be downloaded all at once.

Comment: Tried it, doesnt work. Also says its deprecated. I believe the background downloader that is inside MediaElement just doesnt Dispose. But tried your HttpRandomAccessStream and worked perfectly!.

Comment: Have a look at [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19295826/5697616). Contextually might be different but you might be able to force the stream to drop by changing the `isEnabled` to `false` then doing your standard `.Stop()` and nulling in the handler. Could also force a dispose

Comment: Have you tried `.Close()` yet? as `.Stop()` only resets it to be played from the beginning. Try closing the stream.

Comment: @Gabe isEnabled, Close() and Stop() or any similar doesn't exist.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [MediaElementWithHttpClient](https://github.com/kiewic/MediaElementWithHttpClient) in some other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594659/how-to-play-a-video-stream-that-requires-authentication/18630815#comment59048750_18630815) in a comment made by @kiewic. I can manage the stream and download process and easily dispose it.

```
 HttpRandomAccessStream videoStream = await HttpRandomAccessStream.CreateAsync(new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(), videoUrl);
 mediaElement.SetSource(videoStream, videoStream.ContentType);
```